# server reached pm.max_children setting (5)

Tags: php, nginx

Sorry, I am new and deleted my question thinking I had posted some info I should not have. I am posting the edited question once again:

In our website, php5-fpm takes care of the PHP calls made by the browser.
We have received a lot of outages/`504`s lately.
Now, I checked the php5-fpm logs to correlate with the timestamps of `504` in our access logs and this is what I got in the php5-fpm logs:

> WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it

Please observe that the php5-fpm was not able to handle the connections since it has a current limit of `pm.max_children` setting set only to 5 (please see below) and is way too less based on our workload:

```
unknown@xxxx:~# cat /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf | grep "pm.max_children =" pm.max_children = 5
```

My question is, how do I calculate the new value? I have 4 GB of RAM and the DB is running on a diff server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out the correct value, we need to find the average memory being used by one php-fpm process.

Active php-fpm processes memory consumption:
`root@example:~# ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' | grep php-fpm`

- `111.50 Mb php-fpm: pool www`
- `55.60 Mb php-fpm: pool www`
- `52.25 Mb php-fpm: pool www`
- `12.45 Mb php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)`
- `0.31 Mb grep php-fpm`
- **Now, for your specific case:**
- Average memory consumption per process: (111.50+55.60+52.25)/3 = 73.12 Mb
- Total available memory = 4000 Mb and since DB is running of a separate server, it would be safe to consume 3000 Mb of memory.
- So, the new numbers of pm.max_children based on the above calculation = 3000/74 = 40.54 ~ **40**
- Upon setting the correct value, you should not see pm.max_children error/warning in your php-fpm logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not see the error messages after changing the value.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement st_rt_dl_8's answer, if php-fpm is running inside a container which is missing the `ps` command but all the processes are being run as a specific user, say `www-data`, then the following can be used to get memory size (assuming awk is available):

```
for i in `ls -l /proc/ | awk '/www-data/{print $9}'`; \
do grep VmRSS /proc/$i/status; \
done | awk '{n = $2 / 1024; print n, "Mb"}'
57.2773 Mb
57.8555 Mb
55.5742 Mb
32.5898 Mb
32.7422 Mb
```

And to calculate the average add the following pipe `... | awk 'BEGIN {n=0; sum=0} {n = n + 1; sum = sum + $1} END {print sum / n}'`.